# MaterialUI: Paper or Card title

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Designing a `React` application, what I want is having the title of a `Card` or `Paper` on the top border with some indention from left side, like this:

[image]

I searched a lot and couldn't find a generic way to do so. Should I create a customised component or there's way for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want it to look like, but you can achieve something like that by using the `fieldset` and `legend` elements.

It might look like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Current</legend>
  // Content within border.
</fieldset>
```

Result:

[image: Example of fieldset]

This approach is used by Material-UI for the "Outlined" variant of TextField ([demo here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#outlined)). The code that handles this aspect is the `NotchedOutline` component ([source here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline.js)).

You can also fairly easily do something yourself via a `position` attribute to move a title element up over the border. This would actually allow you to use one of those `material-ui` components to provide most of the styles, and then just move the title on to the border.

Checkout this Codepen for an examples: https://codepen.io/codingmatty/pen/bOXKpZ

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for adding the context of `NotchedOutline` in the Material-UI library.